# Responsive html5: percentage vs media queries

Tags: html, responsive-design

I am working on a simple html 5 game similar to http://www.ebaumsworld.com/games/play/80617036/.

I need to make the game responsive and I wanted to ask if I should go use **CSS media queries** or if I should just go for a **percentage-based lay-out** using percentage dimensions for the width and height of elements.

Which would the best way to go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between a **fluid lay-out** and the use of **media queries** has been written out here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24406/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-fluid-and-responsive-design

A **fluid or percentage-based lay-out** is used when the lay-out should be similar on every screen. It keeps the same spatial weighing for all elements, regardless of the screen size.

**Responsive design (media queries)** is used to change the lay-out on different screen sizes.

From the limited information available on what you're trying to achieve, I would opt for a combination of both. Use percentage-based dimensions for sizing, and use media queries to ensure that the blocks don't cover 90% of a 32" screen for instance...